# Logitech non-gaming wireless mouse with a clicking scroll wheel?

Tags: wireless, mice, logitech

I have an old Logitech M505 mouse and I really like both the ergonomic form factor and the fact that it's from Logitech (the Unifying Receiver is handy). I looks like this:

[image: Logitech M505]

But this is discontinued and it has a few problems of its own, so I'd like to find a new similar mouse from Logitech.

But it must have a **clicking scroll wheel** (so rotating the scroll wheel clicks into set steps instead of smoothly scrolling). Also the **scroll wheel needs to be the middle mouse button** (as opposed to having a separate button below that acts as the middle mouse button). It should also have a **similar form factor** (meaning no weird gaming mice that look like they're an Autobot or Decepticon). Other features (like additional buttons) are okay but not required.

Comment: Today, most mouse have a scroll wheel which can click. I would recommend you to go through stores and try the demo that are available, you'll find one pretty quickly, even if you stick to Logitech.

Comment: @TheBird956 It seems to me that Logitech is taking the route of making their mice *not* click. I guess it's desirable for web browsing, but how are you supposed to use it for things like switching weapons in games or flipping through a list of items where each click is an item? I can't find any from Logitech that fit my needs and I don't think a physical store will be an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Logitech MX Master](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-master) has a configurable scroll wheel which you can customize to either click-by-click or autoscroll.

Quote (emphasis mine):

> ### Speed-adaptive scroll wheel
>
> Scroll through long documents or web pages faster and easier. The precision wheel auto-shifts from click-to-click to hyper-fast scroll.
>
> ***Logitech Options™ software lets you customize this experience.***

- The scroll wheel is also the middle mouse button
- Ergonomic form factor that's not specific to gaming

[image]

Comment: Although it's a bit bigger and bulkier of the form factor in the M505 that looks like it has all the features I want. I also saw the MX Anywhere 2 mouse which is the form factor of the M505 but unfortunately they made the mouse wheel engage/disengage smooth scrolling instead of working as the middle click button. I really wish Logitech would stop overlooking the importance of middle click.

Comment: @Keavon I haven't tried the MX Anywhere product line, but the Logitech SetPoint software usually allows you to reconfigure most of the additional buttons. Was it not possible to do so for the wheel?

Comment: From what I can tell from some videos, clicking the mouse button down physically engages and disengages the mouse's click-to-click/smooth scrolling toggle so I wouldn't think it could be rebound with software. But I will ask about it on the Logitech forums with my fingers crossed!

Comment: I posted that here, for reference http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Possible-to-use-the-scroll-wheel-for-middle-click-with-the-MX/td-p/1440564

Answer (score 3):

Logitech's wireless mice with Unifying Receivers all have smooth-scrolling middle mouse buttons as far as I know.

[This listing](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice) of all Unifying devices out right now has some good alternatives for you. The [M510](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-mouse-m510) is one of the more robust, larger mice they make. Possibly the closest you'll get to the late M505 (RIP) is the [M325](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-mouse-m325) which is almost the same size and has the same features aside from being newer. Based on what you described, I think these would be your best bets.

Comment: Looks like the M325 has micro-precise scrolling (not clicking). The M510 looks like it might be worth a shot although I'm a little wary of the form factor. Thanks for the list.